# Display random photos on my website in slider

Tags: jquery, html

I have slider on my website and I want to display random photos inside. My html code is below:

```
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">
      <img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" 
           style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto;
                  margin-right:auto;" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="caption">
         <a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">
          iPhone <strong>7</strong>
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I have about 20 list items and my script in jQuery is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  display = 6;
  var divs = $('.phone').get().sort(function(){
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
  }).slice(0,6);
  $(divs).show();
});
```

But this script doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Comment: *Doesn't work*?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reorder your elements by yourself in a `for` loop :

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('.phone').length; i++) {
    j = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.phone').length);
    $('.phone').eq(i).before($('.phone').eq(j));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script does work as you can see in this snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  display = 6;
  var divs = $('.phone').get().sort(function(){
    return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5;
  }).slice(0,6);
  $(divs).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="swiper-slide item telef" data-id="1" style="width:250px; height:10px;">
  <div class="phone" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://xxx.pl/pl/xxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb"><img src="<?= $basePath ?>images/iphone7_sl.png" style="width:130px; height:250px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;" alt=""></a>
    <div class="caption"><a href="http://xxxx.pl/pl/xxxxx/prestizowy/_/apple_iphone_7_256_gb">iPhone <strong>7</strong></a></div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: It works but when I use this code, in my slider are empty places. It show 6 reandom photos but there are empty places inside. How to avoid this?

Comment: That's another issue and another question. However, you are hiding/showing the divs inside the li's. The slider shows li's - if you remove its contents its still there. You need to remove() the li's and reset the slider, so it calculates what it needs with only the remaining elements.